# Jquery ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
var html ="";
var $that ="";
var $url ="";

function pop_open() {
    var contents = $(this).html();

    if (contents.match("^http")) {
        console.log('contents',contents);
        $that = $(this);
        $url = contents;

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "AjaxUpdate/getHtml",
            context: $that,
            data: {u: 'http://stackoverflow.com'},
            dataType: 'html',
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }).done(function(html) {
            $link = $('<a href="myreference.html" class="p1" data-html="true" data-bind="popover">');
            $link.data('content', html);

            console.log('$link1',$link);
            $(this).html($link);
            $that = $(this);

            // Trigger the popover to open
            $link = $(this).find('a');
            $link.popover("show");
        });
    }
}

function pop_closed() {
    $(this) =$that;
    console.log('this2 ',$that);
    $link = $that.find('a');
    console.log('$link2 ',$link);
    $link.popover("hide");
    $that.html($url);
}

$('td').hover(pop_open, pop_closed);
```

In the console , I am getting:

```
ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
    $(this) =$that;
```

I am getting the error in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you *expect* that assignment to do?  It's incorrect, but I don't know what to suggest as an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The left-hand side

```
$(this)
```

is a function call, and that cannot be the target of an assignment statement.

Comment: More could be said on this topic, but I don't know what the OP wants it to do.

Comment: In pop_open(), I was trying to pass a reference to a specific td in a table to a global variable $that. In pop_closed I assumed you could reset the jquery context to $that so that I can close the popover at this td.

Comment: If what I'm doing is wrong how do you pass the context to jquery in pop_closed?

Comment: @user61629 there's really no such thing as a "jquery context". If the `$that` variable hasn't been touched since the `pop_open()` code ran, then it should still contain the same reference to the same jQuery object; you don't need to assign it to anything. Just use it.

Comment: function pop_closed() {
    $(this) =$that;     in this function $that scope will not be available

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd what??

Comment: @user61629 anyway because your "pop_closed" function is called as a handler directly by jQuery, you can just use `$(this)` directly because jQuery will call your handler such that `this` is bound to the `<td>` element involved.

Comment: Change popup close function to    function pop_closed() {
    $link = $(this).find('a');
    $link.popover("hide");
    $that.html($url);
}

Answer (score 1):

**Change Close function to**

```
function pop_closed() {
        $link = $(this).find('a');
        $link.popover("hide");
        $that.html($url);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nadeemmnn, I used your code and it does work. I selected Pointy as the right answer because he answered the original question. Thank you for your help.